# DOM to parse Facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, parsing, dom

I am trying to parse messages from a public Facebook fan page wall, but it returns a blank page.

```
$source = "http://www.facebook.com/?sk=wall&filter=2";
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);
$message = $xml->xpath("//span[@class='messageBody']");

return (string)$message[0] . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another approach would be to use the JSON from the Graph API

```
$posts = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/swagbucks/posts')
);
foreach($posts->data as $post) {
    echo $post->message, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as well. I thank you for the contribution.

Comment: @jennier: Please note that with this approach you need to deal with the paging.

Comment: @ifaour only if you want more than what is on the first page anyways. Given that she tried to fetch the posts via DOM, it's feasible to assume @jennifer didnt care about more than those that are on the page.

Comment: True, it's just a heads-up for @jennifer.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method, which you are using, expects the HTML content as a parameter -- and not an URL.

Here, you are trying to interpret your URL as some HTML content -- and not what it links to.

using this method, you might want to try with one that works on a file, or a remonte content, such as [**`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** the right way to fetch data from Facebook, and it's clear that you want to avoid creating a Facebook Application.

But the good news is that you can still use the FQL, try the below query in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20message%0AFROM%20stream%0AWHERE%20source_id=19292868552%0AAND%20is_hidden%20=%200%0AAND%20actor_id=19292868552).

In the below query, we queried the [`stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table to get the [Facebook Developers](https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers) page's public feeds:

```
SELECT message
FROM stream
WHERE source_id=19292868552
AND is_hidden = 0
AND filter_key='owner'
```

It'll return all the "*public*" feeds of the page. Obviously you may need retrieve more fields to create a meaningful result.

---

*You need to provide a valid `access_token` to even access public posts. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/).*