# parse facebook page query

Tags: php, facebook, parsing

I was wondering if someone knew a way of parsing the results of a query done through the search bar in Facebook. I don't manage to get around that "see more reults" button at the end, and I would like to find a way of getting all the results of the search.

I guess a DOM parser is not the solution, since it will only scan the results available on the page:

[DOM to parse Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289147/dom-to-parse-facebook-wall)

Thank you in advance!

Guillermo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, all the results that show after "see more results" is clicked is loaded dynamically via AJAX. Your goal, then, will be to replicate that functionality by manually calling the URL that Facebook calls and getting the results from that (provided that Facebook doesn't use unique tokens to validate the loading of more results in the URL).

I would suggest that you see if you can find the URL that Facebook uses to load more search results.

Comment: Thank you @nickjyc. Do you think FB will be as kind as to provide such URLs?

Comment: I doubt it. You'll probably have to dig through the Javascript. Needless to say, it is not going to be easy finding that one URL.