# Use HTML DOM parser to pull all the public posts from a facebook fan page

Tags: php, html, facebook, dom

[DOM to parse Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5289147/1792570) answers the same question but when i try the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289257/1792570 , i get an error message like this

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">104Requires valid signaturemethodfql.queryquerySELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id=37122264757 AND is_hidden = 0

Is it because FQL has been depricated?

I am using this approach because otherwise, using HTML dom parser just returns a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull the public posts of a [Facebook Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), you need an `access_token`:

- an app or user access token for public and non-demographically restricted pages
- a user access_token for restricted pages that the current user is
  able to view (no special permissions required)

Once you have that, it's a simple API call to [`PAGE_ID/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552/feed) or [`PAGE_ID/posts`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552/posts).

Also please note that FQL is **not** deprecated.